# Setting up an automated pdf comparison on a server

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pip, automated-tests, comparison

Documentation is generated for every new build. I want to automate the process of comparing the new pdf with the old one and outputting the differences onto a text or image file. I also have the option of comparing large HTML folders or chm files(which is complicated as they are compiled files). How should I go about doing this? (I am looking for freeware Python tools)

I have looked into pdf-diff, a Python tool that does exactly what I want. But since I am working on a windows machine with no visual studio, when I try to install it using pip, I get the error "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, you should strongly prefer plain text or marked-up text (*e.g.*, HTML) to an image or image-like file (*e.g.*, PDF) for this purpose. It will be much easier to compare text-based files than anything like a PDF.